# Winform, ListBox datasource to Dictionary<string, string> conversion?

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding, dictionary, listbox

In winform application, binding the Listbox with Dictionary via BindingSource property.

How do I get this BindingSource back to original Dictionary by type casting?

Eg:

```
Dictionary<string, string> objDic = getData();
OrderedDictionry ord = GetOrderedDict(objDic)
listBox.DataSource = new BindingSource(ord , null);
listBox.DisplayMember = "Value";
listBox.ValueMember = "Key";
```

Now, I want same Dictionary type value from `listBox.DataSource` for Linq query!!.

Eg:

```
var r = from t in (listBox.DataSource as Dictionary<string, string>).AsEnumaerable()
        select t;
```

throws error?

How to type cast to dictionary ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to cast a BindingSource to a Dictionary. You need to cast the BindingSource's *DataSource*.

I don't think you can *cast* from `OrderedDictionary` to `Dictionary<>`, but it would be easy to just reconstruct the `Dictionary<string, string>:`

```
    BindingSource bs = (BindingSource)listBox1.DataSource;
    OrderedDictionary ord = (OrderedDictionary)bs.DataSource;
    Dictionary<string, string> dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();

    foreach (DictionaryEntry item in ord)
        dict.Add(item.Key.ToString(), item.Value.ToString());
```

If you want a LINQ version, you could do:

```
   BindingSource bs = (BindingSource)listBox1.DataSource;
   OrderedDictionary ord = (OrderedDictionary)bs.DataSource;        

   var dict = ord.Cast<DictionaryEntry>().ToDictionary(d => d.Key, d => d.Value);
```

Comment: If 'var r' is 'Dictionary<string, string> r' , then how to cast this?

Comment: Error:  Unable to cast object of type 'System.Collections.Specialized.OrderedDictionary' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,System.String]'.

Comment: I didn't notice the part about OrderedDictionary! See my edit.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT 2 - after further discussion/checks**:

```
Dictionary<string, string> A = (from t in ((OrderedDictionary)(((BindingSource)listBox1.DataSource).DataSource)).Cast<KeyValuePair<string, string>>() select t).ToDictionary(d => d.Key, d => d.Value);
```

Comment: Error: (Dictionary<string, string>)(((BindingSource)listbox.DataSource)) Cannot convert type 'System.Windows.Forms.BindingSource' to 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string,string>'

Comment: you didn't copy the code but changed it and omitted the second `.DataSource` ... please copy the complete line from my answer...

Comment: ((Dictionary<string, string>)(((BindingSource)lbAvailable.DataSource).DataSource)) Cannot cast '((System.Windows.Forms.BindingSource)(((System.Windows.Forms.ListControl)(this.lbAvailable)).DataSource)).DataSource' (which has an actual type of 'System.Collections.Specialized.OrderedDictionary') to 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string,string>' System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string,string>

Comment: See Edit -- ordered dictionary as DataSource. As i need to order the list item on remove/add items in list box!!!!

Comment: 'lbAvailable' is actually ListBox control!

Comment: see my edit to account for `OrderedDictionary` and the final cast to `Dictionary<string,string>`

Comment: @Yahia let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2560/discussion-between-dhana-and-yahia)